# Groovy: how to run a JUnit-Test (using JUnit 5)?

Tags: groovy, junit5

I am writing my first larger Groovy application and I want to define me a couple of unit-tests but can't get these to execute. I keep getting an exception `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOOP`. I boiled this down to a really simple example which looks like so:

```
package example_project;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import groovy.test.GroovyTestCase

public class FirstUnitTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    void testJunitTestExecution() {
        Assertions.fail("Heureka - this test got executed!")
    }
}
```

This "unit-test" should be executable within Eclipse or via Maven.

When I execute that inside Eclipse (using "Run as... --> JUnit Test" using JUnit 5 test runner) I get the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOOP
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

When executed via Maven (using "mvn test") I get

```
[INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ FirstUnitTest  ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] NOOP
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.342 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-09T16:18:10+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So - apparently the same error, even though there is no stack trace.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>example_project</artifactId>
    <name>example_project</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- We also specify the file encoding of our source files, to avoid a warning -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <groovy.version>4.0.12</groovy.version>
        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.8-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            ... some plugins re. packaging removed for brevity ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using Groovy v4.0.12, Eclipse 2023-06 (v4.28.0) with the Groovy Plugin and Maven v3.9.4.

What am I missing? Why is my test-method not executed?

Comment: Please show your Mavem pom.xml

Comment: Not helping this problem, but have you tried Spock for unit and integration tests? https://spockframework.org/

Comment: @johanneslink I added my pom to the question (I removed a few plugin specs re. packaging, but these should have no relevance here).

Answer (score 0):

After all-in-all about a day's worth of fiddling with this BS I gave up and I am now using JUnit 4.

After switching the TestRunner-setting to JUnit4 in Eclipse the UT immediately found and properly executed. And after adding

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

to my pom.xml it was also properly found and executed via `mvn test`.

Unfortunately - I have to say - this matches my former experience with JUnit-5 / Jupiter. I *never* had a project so far where getting things to work with JUnit 5 was *not* a hassle, while with JUnit 4 things always were a snap.
Sure, in theory JUnit 5 has a few cool features but IMHO they are simply not worth such issues!
YMMV but I guess I'll simply stick to JUnit 4.

Comment: I think you gave in too fast. Starting with the JUnit/Jupiter starter projects has always worked for me; have you tried those? In your case I assume that the Groovy plug-in must be told to put the classfiles to the correct location or work in the correct Maven phase.

Comment: That may well be, but - as I wrote - I did quite a lot of searching and tried a lot of things, but none had worked. There also were not very many helpful results. Running JUnit5 tests with Groovy does not exactly seem to be a very popular subject.